# How to encrypt JWT payload javascript and decrypt in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, jwt

I am trying to encrypt a JWT payload in javascript and then decrypt it in my Ruby app.  I found a  simple Ruby encryption/decryption tool, but I do not know how to do the encryption side in javascript.  Is there a way to accomplish this encryption in javascript so that my Ruby backend can decrypt it?

```
def encrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').encrypt
    cipher.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key
    s = cipher.update(self) + cipher.final

    s.unpack('H*')[0].upcase
end

def decrypt(key)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').decrypt
    cipher.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key
    s = [self].pack("H*").unpack("C*").pack("c*")

    cipher.update(s) + cipher.final
end

puts plain = 'confidential'           # confidential
puts key = 'secret'                   # secret
puts cipher = plain.encrypt(key)      # 5C6D4C5FAFFCF09F271E01C5A132BE89

puts cipher.decrypt('guess')          # raises OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError
puts cipher.decrypt(key)              # confidential
```

Comment: The cipher choices in your example are incredibly outdated and very likely not secure. Very often, JWT is also difficult to implement securely and is often the wrong tool for the job. If you still need to encrypt stuff, if possible, you should not try no implement low-level cryptography yourself but use higher-level abstractions as e.g. provided by libsodium (which you can use with [rbnacl](https://github.com/RubyCrypto/rbnacl) on the Ruby side and [libsodium.js](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js/) in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. There is standard for that: encrypted JWT (JWE) => [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516).
Moreover and as mentioned by Holger Just, you should follow the [Best Current Practices](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8725) and avoid unsecured algorithms.

https://jwt.io/ lists a lot of libraries that can offer more than the usual signed tokens (JWS). Unfortunately, at that time no Ruby library support JWE.